# Java Date and Timestamp from instance of ZonedDateTime UTC

Tags: java, sql, date, timestamp

I have a java application in which I would like the time in UTC. Currently, the code uses a mix of `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp`. To get the time in UTC, the programmer before me used:

For Date:

```
 Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)).toInstant();
```

For Timestamp:

```
 Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
```

However I have run multiple tests myself with this code and both of these lines return the current date/time(in my current timezone). From everything I have read it **appears** that Date/Timestamp does not have a zoneOffset value, but I cannot find a concrete statement of this.

Is there anyway to keep the timeZone (UTC) within the Date or Timestamp objects, or do I need to do some refactoring and use the actual ZonedDateTime object throughout my application? Also will this ZonedDateTime object be compatible with the current Timestamp object for sql?

Example:

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
    Date date = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
    System.out.println("ZonedDateTime: " + zonedDateTime);
    System.out.println("Timestamp: " + timestamp);
    System.out.println("Date: " + date);
}
```

Output:

```
 ZonedDateTime: 2017-04-06T15:46:33.099Z
 Timestamp: 2017-04-06 10:46:33.109
 Date: Thu Apr 06 10:46:33 CDT 2017
```

Comment: "...return the current date/time(in my current timezone)...", maybe you have just used the method `toString()` on `java.util.Date` to conclude that, but this method only uses external default timezone to print itself. The offset or timezone is never part of `java.util.Date`, and its true state is rather reflected by the method `getTime()`. So please clarify what you have really done.

Comment: Date and Timestamp both store time in GMT. Switching the time zone only changes the display value.

Comment: There is no logical difference between `Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant())` and `new Date()`. Except former is a lot more confusing.

Comment: Normally I would not recommend looking at the source, since a class’s behavior is defined by its contract (javadoc), but as of Java 8, [the source of java.util.Date](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Date.java/) shows it has only two instance fields:  a long value and a ‘BaseCalendar’ object used only by now-deprecated methods (which date back to when the Calendar class didn’t exist and the Date class was trying to provide all calendar-related functionality).  It just wraps a millisecond value;  it retains no timezone information.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()  // Capture the current moment in UTC with a resolution up to nanoseconds.
```

Use only *java.time* classes. Avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes added before Java 8.

## Using java.time

The programmer before you was making use of the new modern java.time classes that now supplant the notoriously troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, `Timestamp`.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction). To get the current moment in UTC is utterly simple: `Instant.now`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

### Converting

You should stick to the java.time classes, and avoid the legacy classes. But if absolutely necessary such as interfacing with old code not yet updated for java.time, you may convert to/from java.time. Look to new methods on old classes. The legacy class `java.util.Date` equivalent is `Instant`.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( myInstant); // To legacy from modern.
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();  // To modern from legacy.
```

### JDBC

Avoid the legacy date-time classes. Use java.time classes instead.

Your [JDBC 4.2](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) compliant [driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) may be able to directly address java.time types by calling [`PreparedStatement::setObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-) and [`ResultSet::getObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

… and …

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

If not, fall back to using the java.sql types, but as briefly as possible. Use new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
myPreparedStatement.setTimestamp( … , java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant ) ) ;
```

… and …

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getTimestamp( … ).toInstant() ;
```

### No need for `ZonedDateTime`

Notice that we had no need for your mentioned `ZonedDateTime` as you said you were only interested in UTC. The `Instant` objects are always in UTC. That means that original code you quoted:

```
Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)).toInstant();
```

…could have simply been shortened to:

```
Date.from( Instant.now() ) ;
```

Note that `java.util.Date` is always in UTC as well. However, its `toString` unfortunately applies the JVM’ current default time zone implicitly while generating the String. This anti-feature creates no end of confusion as you can see by searching on Stack Overflow.

If you want to see your `Instant` object’s UTC value through the lens of a region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time), assign a time zone `ZoneId` to get a `ZoneDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `CDT` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Why do you recommend using `setObject()` instead of using the `java.sql` type `timestamp`?

Comment: @mFeinstein Because `Timestamp` is an abomination of poor Class design. The *java.time* framework was designed and adopted by Sun, Oracle, and the JCP to entirely replace the legacy date-time classes. One of the main points of JDBC 4.2 update was this transition to the modern *java.time* classes.

Comment: How does `setObject` behaves on this? Will it save my `ZonedDateTime` as a blob? Will I be able to run queries on the data saved on the database? Does it work for all `java.time` values as `Instant` and `Period`?

Comment: I am currently using `Timestamp` from an `Instant` and all `TIMESTAMP` data on my MySQL database is in UTC and I can search it and read it easily, what am I losing then?

Comment: @mFeinstein As of JDBC 4.2, no need to ever touch the `java.sql.Timestamp` class again, nor any other date-time related class outside the *java.time* package.  I am a Postgres kind of guy, but apparently the `TIMESTAMP` data type in MySQL represents a moment in UTC, and is akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Therefore, you should use `java.time.Instant` for exchanging values with columns of that type. If you have a `ZonedDateTime` object, simply call its `toInstant` method to converse with your database via your JDBC driver. After retrieving, call `Instant::atZone`.

Comment: Is Postgres timestamp different than MySQL? I am planning to learn Postgresql with Postgis shortly

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this "no java.sql.Timestamp" approach is that code becomes less readable and more prone to error since we are passing a generic object to the database and not a strictly typed one.... So I get inclined to use Timestamps just on the database operations, as your recommendations to use them as briefly as possible, so the database operation is known at compile time and very readable... But I am still thinking about it, maybe I won't use it...

Comment: @mFeinstein Postgres and MySQL are two leading open-source relational databases. One is vastly superior to the other, but which one depends on who you ask. ;-)  If asking me, the blue elephant is my mascot.

Comment: I read a good article about it, my conclusion is that MySQL is better for random access, whereas Postgresql is better for long running queries and GIS.... But I was asking more about the different timestamps since you mentioned it, but no problem, I will have to read it shortly anyways

Comment: FYI: If you are interested in using PostgreSQL and its JDBC driver, then the documentation has some additional useful information on [Using Java 8 Date and Time classes](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/java8-date-time.html) (e.g. the note that ZonedDateTime, Instant and OffsetTime / TIME WITH TIME ZONE are not supported).

Answer (score 6):

In Java, `Date` represents a point in time. It's not related to timestamp. When you call `toString()` method of a `Date` object, it converts that time to Platform's default Timestamp, e.g. Following will print date/time in UTC (as it sets default timezone to UTC):

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
Date date = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
System.out.println("ZonedDateTime: " + zonedDateTime);
System.out.println("Timestamp: " + timestamp);
System.out.println("Date: " + date);
```