# Date one day backwards after select from MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc, timezone

I have timezone related problem.

I have a program in JAVA and MySql database.
I do not use any ORM, but I  have custom jdbc library which uses mysql connector java v 6.0.4

I send settings as part of the connection string as:

```
 serverTimezone - America/Chicago
 useTimezone - true
 useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift - false
 useLegacyDatetimeCode - false
```

I try to select a date from db e.g `2019-02-13`.

Database is located at time zone US/Eastern and server running java program is located at time zone America/Chicago.

There is no way to change the location / time zone of any of the servers.

In Java, I get a date one day backwards (`2019-02-12`). 
Problem is caused because of timestamp -

`1550034000` is `2019-02-13 00:00:00` in US/Eastern

but

`1550034000` is `2019-02-12 23:00:00` in America/Chicago

So as the result I have `java.sql.Date` object with date `2019-02-12`.
There is no help to add timezone offset because time information is cut off from date.

Can you propose some solution on how to get a proper date without timezone shift?

Edit: I am using `serverTimezone` setting but I am not sure if value should be timezone that database is using or it is just overriding timezone of JVM / server running the application.

Comment: Show the code (inserts and selects)? Show the table structure, specificity the types of the date objects.

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43270268/2185630) as it could give you some clues.

Comment: It may require modifying your custom JDBC library, but if the column datatype is `date`, retrieve into a `LocalDate`, not a `java.sql.Date`. The latter has design problems (as you have encountered, but not limited to that) and is long outdated. `LocalDate` is from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @danblack I was able to simulate the problem with simple select -  SELECT CURDATE() as 'date';

Comment: The _1550034000 is 2019-02-13 00:00:00 in US/Eastern ... in America/Chicago_ part is correct behavior. What exactly do you want? Show the times relative to Eastern time to people in Chicago?

Comment: @SalmanA I wanted to show dates to people in Chicago. I do not care about the hours and minutes. And the dates are for both zones same except for 2 hours a day.

Comment: Are you able to modify your custom JDBC library to return `java.time.LocalDate` instead of (or in addition to) `java.sql.Timestamp` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I have read that you can’t in your case, but for other readers I would like to state that the general recommendation is to run everything in UTC, at least when you span more than one time zone. So this would have been the best solution to your issue.

Second, as both I and Gord Thompson have mentioned in comments, the second best solution is to handle dates as `LocalDate`, not `java.sql.Date`. While the latter only *pretends* not to have time of day, it really has design problems that make it hard to solve your issue. A `LocalDate` really *is* a date without time of day and without time zone, so should be a bet that is a lot safer (except that database drivers that convert incorrectly to and from `LocalDate` have been heard of; I keep my fingers crossed; again running everything in UTC would eliminate those bugs too). **Edit:** Assuming you can modify your custom JDBC library, here’s how to get a `LocalDate` from a `ResultSet`:

```
    LocalDate correctDateDirectlyFromDatabase
            = yourResultSet.getObject("yourDateColumn", LocalDate.class);
```

It requires at least JDBC 4.2, you probably have that.

If none of the above is available to you, here comes the way to mend the incorrect `Date` you got from the database. It’s a bit of a hack, but will work.

```
import java.sql.Date;

// …

    // Modern ID of the time zone previously known as US/Eastern
    ZoneId datebaseTimeZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

    Date dateFromDatabase = new Date(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1_550_034_000));
    System.out.println("Date as retrieved from database (or pretending): " + dateFromDatabase);

    long epochMillis = dateFromDatabase.getTime();
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis)
            .atZone(datebaseTimeZone);
    LocalDate realDate = dateTime.toLocalDate();
    // Sanity check
    if (! realDate.atStartOfDay(datebaseTimeZone).equals(dateTime)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to convert date correctly from " + datebaseTimeZone + " time zone");
    }

    System.out.println("Date is " + realDate);
```

When I ran this in America/Chicago time zone, it printed:

> ```
> Date as retrieved from database (or pretending): 2019-02-12
> Date is 2019-02-13
> ```

I have tried running it in other time zones. In some time zones the first line prints `2019-02-12`, in others `2019-02-13`. The last line prints `2019-02-13` in all time zones I have tried.

Now I have given you a `LocalDate`. That’s good, this is what you should want to use in your further processing. In case you need a `java.sql.Date` for another legacy API that you don’t want to change just yet, convert back to a *correct* `java.sql.Date` this way:

```
    Date oldfashionedJavaSqlDate = Date.valueOf(realDate);
    System.out.println("Date converted back to " + oldfashionedJavaSqlDate);
```

> Date converted back to 2019-02-13

And when I say correct, it requires that no one is tampering with the default time zone of your JVM, which is easy for any program running in the JVM to do.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Another approach that occurred to me would be to retrieve `SELECT CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)` as a `Timestamp` and then use `getTime()` to determine the (milli)seconds to use for a `ZoneOffset`. It wouldn't require prior knowledge of the server configuration, although DST/Summer_Time might throw a wrench into things.

Comment: Yes, I’m afraid that summer time/DST renders this approach too risky. Upside is of course that it would be more flexible in case the database time zone is not known or can change.

Comment: I created function that converts java.sql.date from db to LocalDate as you suggested and later I am using java.time API. Or is there some way to tell driver to convert date result using java.time automatically? Later I created function to compare offsets of these two timezones and added the offset in seconds between them to get the desired result, but decided to use your solution to convert because it is more elegant :)

Comment: Yes, @peter.cambal, if your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 or later, it will give you a `LocalDate` directly. See my little edit.

Comment: @peter.cambal - You may need to upgrade your MySQL Connector/J to something newer than 6.0.4 in order to have `.getObject("yourDateColumn", LocalDate.class)` work reliably. MySQL Connector/J had (and [still has](https://bugs.mysql.com/?id=93444)) some quirks regarding `java.time` objects.

Answer (score 2):

> I am using `serverTimezone` setting but I am not sure if value should be timezone that database is using or it is just overriding timezone of JVM / server running the application.

`serverTimezone=America/Chicago` means "interpret the results from the server as if the server was using the `America/Chicago` time zone regardless of the default time zone that the server is configured to use". So if you used that setting in your connection string you would get `Timestamp` values converted to `America/Chicago` even though the default time zone for the server is apparently `America/New_York`.

However, before committing to that approach you'd want to confirm that the server really is using `America/New_York` (which would presumably switch back and forth between Eastern Standard Time and Eastern Daylight Time) and not a fixed offset like UTC-5 (which would always stay on "Eastern Standard Time").

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This helped me to understand the issue more