# How can I get the UTC-converted Java timestamp of current local time?

Tags: java, jdbc, datetime-format

Could somebody please help with getting UTC-converted Java timestamp of current local time?
The main goal is to get current date and time, convert into UTC Timestamp and then store in Ignite cache as a Timestamp `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnnnn]`.

My attempt was `Timestamp.from(Instant.now())`. However, it still considers my local timezone `+03:00`. I am getting `'2020-02-20 10:57:56'` as a result instead of desirable `'2020-02-20 07:57:56'`.

How can I get UTC-converted Timestamp?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259722/java-date-and-timestamp-from-instance-of-zoneddatetime-utc 
Have a look at this link for information regarding UTC timestamps.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead your modern database driver or JPA implementation should be able to accept an `OffsetDateTime` in UTC or if needs be, a `LocalDateTime`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(localDateTime.format(formatter));
```

Comment: HH (24h) i.o. hh (12h) but fine. Almost a toString (where a T instead of a space).

Comment: completely agree, just formatted it to the format as expected in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestions! However it returns a String typed value whilst Timestamp is required for storing it as a date&time in Apache Ignite cache.

Comment: Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime.format(formatter)) will work in your case.

Comment: Thanks. The above one worked even without ```.format(formatter)```.
Just ```Timestamp.valueOf(Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime())``` returns ```'2020-02-20 10:24:28'``` in UTC. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

### Don’t use Timestamp

You most probably don’t need a `Timestamp`. Which is good because the `Timestamp` class is poorly designed, indeed a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `Date` class. Both classes are also long outdated. Instead nearly 6 years ago we got java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Since JDBC 4.2 this works with your JDBC driver too, and also with your modern JPA implementation.

### Use OffsetDateTime

For a timestamp the recommended datatype in your database is `timestamp with time zone`. In this case in Java use an `OffsetDateTime` with an offset of zero (that is, UTC). For example:

```
    OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(now);

    PreparedStatement statement = yourDatabaseConnection
            .prepareStatement("insert into your_table (tswtz) values (?);");
    statement.setObject(1, now);
    int rowsInserted = statement.executeUpdate();
```

Example output from the `System.out.println()` just now:

> 2020-02-22T13:04:06.320Z

### Or use LocalDateTime if your database timestamp is without time zone

From your question I get the impression that the datatype in your database is `timestamp` without time zone. It’s only the second best option, but you can pass a `LocalDateTime` to it.

```
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

The rest is the same as before. Example output:

> 2020-02-22T13:05:08.776

### If you do need an old-fashioned java.sql.Timestamp

You asked for a `Timestamp` in UTC. A `Timestamp` is *always* in UTC. More precisely, it’s a point in time independent of time zone, so converting it into a different time zone does not make sense. Internally it’s implemented as a count of milliseconds and nanoseconds since the epoch. The epoch is defined as the first moment of 1970 *in UTC*.

The `Timestamp` class is a confusing class though. One thing that might have confused you is when you print it, thereby implicitly calling its `toString` method. The `toString` method uses the default time zone of the JVM for rendering the string, so prints the time in your local time zone. Confusing. If your datatype in SQL is `timestamp` without time zone, your JDBC driver most probably interprets the `Timestamp` in your time zone for the conversion into an SQL `timestamp`. Which in your case is incorrect since your database uses UTC (a recommended practice). I can think of three possible solutions:

1. Some database engines allow you to set a time zone on the session. I haven’t got any experience with it myself, it’s something I have read; but it may force the correct conversion from your Java `Timestamp` to your SQL `timestamp` in UTC to be performed.
2. You may make an incorrect conversion in Java to compensate for the opposite incorrect conversion being performed between Java and SQL. It’s a hack, not something that I would want to have in my code. I present it as a last resort.

   ```
       LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
       Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(now);
       System.out.println(ts);
   ```

   > 2020-02-22 13:05:08.776

   You notice that it only *appears* to agree with the UTC time above. It‘s the same result you get from the answer by Vipin Sharma except (1) my code is simpler and (2) you’re getting a higher precision, fraction of second is included.
3. Have you database generate the current timestamp in UTC instead of generating it in Java.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- Related question: [Java - Convert java.time.Instant to java.sql.Timestamp without Zone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766674/java-convert-java-time-instant-to-java-sql-timestamp-without-zone-offset)

Comment: Many thanks for greatly detailed answer! This definitely makes sense to me. However it contradicts a bit to my needs. Actually I am working with Apache Ignite data persistence mechanism (which is not SQL itself). Plus the logic of the system is that setter of the 'database-worker' class gets `LocalDateTime.now()` (various timezones users are expected) value and it needs to be stored as a Timestamp in Ignite's cache. Will think of your suggestions and try to integrate it in my work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. Sorry I don’t know Apache Ignite. Sounds like you’ve got yourself an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what the [Ignite docs say](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/data-types#timestamp) you can pass in a 24hr time.
The docs says `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss[.nnnnnnnnn]` so you may be tempted in your code to use this to format your dates but this will lead to times after midday being wrong. Instead, format your dates with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.nnnnnnnnn]`.

Notice the upper case `HH`. If you're using `ZonedDateTime` or Joda's `DateTime` when you call now with UTC `now(UTC)` and then `toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` will store the correct time in UTC.